# Swift4 Core Data how to insert into NSOrderedSet by date?

Tags: core-data, swift4, nsentitydescription, nsorderedset

I have a core data model with one record having a `to many` relationship to photos entity. The relationship is flagged as `ordered` in the data model.

The code below adds a new record at the last index.  I want records to be ordered by date - meaning I have to insert the object at some specific index

```
 let photo = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: photoKey, into: self.managedObjectContext()) as! Photo
```

**Is there a way to have core data perform a block or some operation to determine the correct insertion index for the new record?** Or do I have to calculate it myself?

I'm concerned about order because photo deletions force the need to recalculate the date range of all photos.